# How can I fetch data from an array of objects, pass it through an API end point to .fetch() the needed object value using React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, rest, powerbi-embedded

I'm creating a report dashboard using PowerBI using React and need to pass the embed token value to the backend end point we created to then pass that new value into the PowerBI embed component to display the report properly.

I have the application working if I manually place in the embed token values, but that isn't ideal for multiple reasons (ex. security and time consuming), so I'm trying to automate this within the React app.

How we're displaying the reports manually is through a switch statement since there's multiple reports to choose from and each have the PowerbiEmbedded component placed with the appropriate values pulling from a local JSON file where the report IDs and embed URLs are placed. This is the same file I pasted the tokens for testing/proof of concept and have a separate component handling the fetch request (RequestToken.js below) and a bit lost on how to connect this with the ReportDashboard.js since that's what's handling the display of each report.

Any suggestions and help with this would be greatly appreciated!

---

RequestToken.js

```
import React from "react"
import { groupVariables } from '../constants/reportVariables';


// This will handle token retrieval for each 
class RequestAccessToken extends React.Component {

    state = {
        isLading: true,
        tokenDetails: [],
        error: null
    };

    getTokenDetails() {

        // where we're fetching data from b2b for proof of concept
        axios.get(`/api/token/${accessToken}`)

        // got the API response and receive data in JSON format
        .then(response => 
            response.data.results.map(tokenDetail => ({
                token: `${tokenDetail.token}`
            }))
        )

        .then(tokenDetails => {
            this.setState({
                tokenDetails,
                isLoading: false
            });
        })

        // catch any errors we hit and update the output
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getTokenDetails();
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoading, tokenDetails } = this.state;
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {!isLoading ? (
                    tokenDetails.map(tokenDetail => {
                        const { token } = tokenDetail
                        return (
                            console.log(tokenDetail)
                        );
                    })
                // If there is a delay in data, let's let the user know it's loading
                ) : (
                <h3>Loading...</h3>
                )}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

ReportDashboard.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { reportVariables } from '../constants/reportVariables.js';
import PowerbiEmbedded from 'react-powerbi'

function Reporting({ activeView }) {
  // configure the reportIds and report name in constants/reportVariables.js
  let reportData;

  switch(activeView){
    case 'Business to Consumer':
      reportData = <div>
        <PowerbiEmbedded
          id={reportVariables.reportIds.b2c}
          embedUrl={reportVariables.reportURL.b2c}
          accessToken={reportVariables.reportToken.b2c}
          filterPaneEnabled={false}
          navContentPaneEnabled={false}
          embedType={`report`}
          tokenType={`Embed`}
          permissions={`All`}
        />
      </div>
      break;
    case 'Business to Business': 
      reportData = <div>
      <PowerbiEmbedded
          id={reportVariables.reportIds.b2b}
          embedUrl={reportVariables.reportURL.b2b}
          accessToken={reportVariables.reportToken.b2b}
          filterPaneEnabled={false}
          navContentPaneEnabled={false}
          embedType={`report`}
          tokenType={`embed`}
          permissions={`All`}
        />
    </div>
      break;
    case 'Agent':
      reportData = <div>
      <PowerbiEmbedded
          id={reportVariables.reportIds.agent}
          embedUrl={reportVariables.reportURL.agent}
          accessToken={reportVariables.reportToken.agent}
          filterPaneEnabled={false}
          navContentPaneEnabled={false}
          embedType={`report`}
          tokenType={`embed`}
          permissions={`All`}
        />
    </div>
      break;
    case 'A/B Testing':
      reportData = <div>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lcGoWfXLRpc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      break;
    default: 
      break;
  }

  return(
    <div className='frameDiv'>  
      <style>{`
        .frameDiv{
          justify-content: center;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          width: 85vw;
          height: calc(100vh - 39px);
          background: #ccc;
        }
        .powerbi-frame {
          width: 85vw;
          height: calc(100vh - 39px);
        }
        `}
      </style>

        {reportData}

    </div>
  ); 
}
export default Reporting
```

Comment: Just to confirm, does your question boil down to "how can I pass the token acquired in `RequestAccessToken` to my `Reporting` component?"

Comment: Yes, and to pass the accessToken value declared from the PowerbiEmbedded component in ReportDashboard.js? The tokens are report specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can pass the token to other components, but it all boils down to "pass it as a prop." You can use a React context, centralized state management, or parent/child nesting. Another option, which I think would be the most elegant, would be to create a higher-order component (HOC) that wraps any component with the `RequestAccessToken` component:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'React';

function withAccessToken(accessToken) {
  return Component => props => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
      isLoading: true,
      tokenDetails: [],
      error: null
    });

    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get(`/api/token/${accessToken}`)
        // where we're fetching data from b2b for proof of concept

        // got the API response and receive data in JSON format
        .then(response => 
            response.data.results.map(tokenDetail => ({
                token: `${tokenDetail.token}`
            }))
        )

        .then(tokenDetails => {
            setState({
              tokenDetails,
              isLoading: false
            });
        })

        // catch any errors we hit and update the output
        .catch(error => setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
    }, []);

    const { isLoading, tokenDetails, error } = state;
    return (
      isLoading && <h3>Loading...</h3>
      || error && <h3>Error loading token</h3>
      || <Component {...props} accessToken={tokenDetails}/>
    );
  };
}
```

The way you'd use this would be something like:

```js
const B2BReport = withAccessToken('some-token-name')(({ accessToken }) =>
  <PowerbiEmbedded
    id={reportVariables.reportIds.b2b}
    embedUrl={reportVariables.reportURL.b2b}
    accessToken={accessToken}
    filterPaneEnabled={false}
    navContentPaneEnabled={false}
    embedType={`report`}
    tokenType={`embed`}
    permissions={`All`}
  />
);
```

This creates a new `B2BReport` component which gets an `accessToken` prop injected by the HOC. You'd then render this `<B2BReport/>` component in your `ReportDashboard` component.

Answer (score 0):

RequestAccessToken needs to be rendered *somewhere* right? As of now it’s just sitting there. Import it into your Dashboard component and render it, then you can access your token there.